# Organization in Asp.Net MVC 5 and AngularJS Web App

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm starting to build an ASP.Net MVC 5 App with AngularJS (I'm learning about AngularJS). 
The App is basically an website with Front-End and Backoffice and the major content will be news and events.
And right now came up the following question: How should I generate the views?

The usual way in ASP.Net MVC 5;
With AngularJS controller;

Should I use MVC just to get/post the data on DB? What are the best pratices?

Comment: No real need to use any server side framework to serve angular templates or main page. Can generally consider front end and back end api as 2 completely separate entities